# Theorems continued over multiple pages using amsthm

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I use `amsthm` to define my own `lemma`, `theorem`, and other environments. 
Some are too long to display on one page, which means that they are broken onto multiple pages.

When such an environment is split up, I would like there to be some text e.g.

> **Theorem 0.1 (cont'd)**

and

> **Lemma 0.2 (cont'd)**

or something similar on the following pages of the environment. 
How could I achieve that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    11pt
]{memoir}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyph
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{blindtext} 

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow!15}


\theoremstyle{definition} %Also: plain, definition, remark
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter] 
\AtBeginEnvironment{lemma}{\begin{shaded}}%
\AtEndEnvironment{lemma}{\end{shaded}}%

\theoremstyle{definition} %Also: plain, definition, remark
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\begin{shaded}}%
\AtEndEnvironment{theorem}{\end{shaded}}%



\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\Blindtext
\blindtext
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
\Blindtext
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Compilation of the above code:
[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]
[image: Page 3]

Comment: The `tcolorbox` package can easily achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` package can be used to provide configurable boxes around the theorems etc.,especially breakability is easy with `tcolorbox`. The `title after break={....}` option will display a special title then.

Please note, that `tcolorbox` can setup special `theorem` boxes of its own,but I kept the original definitions.

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    11pt
]{memoir}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyph
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{blindtext} 

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow!15}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{lemmastyle/.style={title={},breakable,colback=shadecolor,enhanced jigsaw,boxrule=0pt,sharp corners,colframe=shadecolor,boxsep=0pt,colbacktitle={shadecolor},coltitle={black},attach title to upper={},
    title after break={Lemma \thelemma\ (continued)}}}

\tcbset{theostyle/.style={title={},breakable,colback=shadecolor,enhanced jigsaw,boxrule=0pt,sharp corners,colframe=shadecolor,boxsep=0pt,colbacktitle={shadecolor},coltitle={black},attach title to upper={},
    title after break={Theorem \thetheorem\ (continued)}}}


\theoremstyle{definition} %Also: plain, definition, remark
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter] 
\AtBeginEnvironment{lemma}{\begin{tcolorbox}[lemmastyle]}%
\AtEndEnvironment{lemma}{\end{tcolorbox}}%

\theoremstyle{definition} %Also: plain, definition, remark
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\begin{tcolorbox}[theostyle]}%
\AtEndEnvironment{theorem}{\end{tcolorbox}}%




\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\Blindtext
\blindtext
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
\Blindtext
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Shorter Version** with `\tcolorboxenvironment`

```
  \documentclass[%
        a4paper,
        11pt
    ]{memoir}

    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyph
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \usepackage{blindtext} 

    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{thmtools}



    \colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow!15}

    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

    \tcbset{lemmastyle/.style={title={},breakable,colback=shadecolor,enhanced jigsaw,boxrule=0pt,sharp corners,colframe=shadecolor,boxsep=0pt,colbacktitle={shadecolor},coltitle={black},attach title to upper={},fonttitle={\bfseries},
        title after break={Lemma \thelemma\ (continued)}}}

    \tcbset{theostyle/.style={title={},breakable,colback=shadecolor,enhanced jigsaw,boxrule=0pt,sharp corners,colframe=shadecolor,boxsep=0pt,colbacktitle={shadecolor},coltitle={black},attach title to upper={}, fonttitle={\bfseries},
        title after break={Theorem \thetheorem\ (continued)}}}

    \theoremstyle{definition} %Also: plain, definition, remark
    \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter] 
    \theoremstyle{definition} %Also: plain, definition, remark
    \newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem} 

    \tcolorboxenvironment{lemma}{lemmastyle}
    \tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{theostyle}





    \begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}
    \Blindtext
    \blindtext
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{lemma}
    \Blindtext
    \end{lemma}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. I added the `fonttitle=\bfseries`, such that the continued titles looked like the original text.

Comment: @brixenDK: Well, that's a good idea of course. Happy TeXing!

Comment: @brixenDK: There's even a shorter version with `\tcolorboxenvironment`, see the update, if you like ;-)